# SidebarPane on extension panel

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created panel and know I want to create SidebarPane for my extension.
Method chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane allow me create panel for "Elements" panel.
Can I do the same thing but for my own panel?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to create a 'panel' that appears in regular web pages for your extension?

Comment: No, I want to create SidebarPane for my Devtools extension panel

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible, except by implements the 'elements panel' implementation by yourself. The feature can be requested at crbug.com.